# Problems reading delta lake files in Databricks

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks, delta-lake, data-lakehouse

In another issue here I was having difficulty reading all the files, someone managed to help me. I managed to read all the files, but can you guys give me some more help?

I'm reading 12 different files, and a new file is only inserted once a year.

In these 12 files, each one refers to a year, and I wanted to insert a column with the year that file refers to.

In the case of files, the first line only has "Fiscal year: 2013", and I wanted to make this column a line for each file, but it reads them all as a single year.

I'm doing it this way:

```
# Extract the year from the file
first_line = spark.read.text(path_files).first()[0]
file_year = re.search(r"\d{4}", first_line).group()
```

Comment: can you please share the sample records for better understanding ?

Comment: I'm sending an example file. To avoid sending multiple files, I sent a file with three spreadsheets, and think that each spreadsheet is like a different file.

In the first line I have the year:2013, year:2014, year:2015

and I want to turn it into a column.

I can transform the column, but when reading all the files, my table looks as if all the years were 2013.

https://github.com/JoyciP/databricks_deltalake

Thank you, I'm on this project alone, and I've been trying different ways for days, uploading the file with the edits is not an option,i can't edit them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the logic for your requirement .

Note : Based on the same file which you have shared, I could not figure out the delimiter of the file . So , I have assumed delimiter of your input file is comma(',').

```
Input file format :

year: 2017  
CITY,COD
abc,123
def,456
geh,789

#getting the year of the data 

var_lines_df = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/input1")
var_first_line = var_lines_rdd.first()[0]
var_year = var_first_line.split(":")[1]
print(var_year)

#creating the dataframe and create a another column based on the Year of the data . 

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
lines_to_skip = 1
lines_rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/input1")
filtered_rdd = lines_rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] >= lines_to_skip).map(lambda x: x[0])
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").csv(filtered_rdd, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df_with_new_column = df.withColumn("year", lit(var_year))
display(df_with_new_column)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u for helping me. I will keep thinking of ways to solve it and find the solution. But without a doubt, you opened up other solutions for me that I hadn’t thought of. For some reason it reads as if all the files are 2018. But in the image you can see that 2013, and 2018 have the same pattern. https://github.com/JoyciP/databricks_deltalake

I took two screenshots, error and file 1 and 2, so you can get an idea of ​​what happens. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: do you have an idea on what is delimiter ?

Comment: the delimiter is ; In these files.

Comment: try this code : https://github.com/JoyciP/databricks_deltalake/compare/main...mllearnng:databricks_deltalake:patch-1

Comment: i did it: https://github.com/JoyciP/databricks_deltalake/blob/main/erross.PNG

But it continues to pull only the year 2018. Even though they are files from 2013 to 2022.

I know that the streaming reads all the files, but is it possible to do a loop before the data streaming inserts the years in the files, and then do the entire bronze level process.

Comment: Based on your requirements , we can process based on the autoloader whenever new files arrived in source folder instead of iterate the all files . Update code here : https://github.com/JoyciP/databricks_deltalake/compare/main...mllearnng:databricks_deltalake:patch-2 . I did't test this code . but logic is straight forward. you can test

Comment: you can share your code what you are trying with error pull only the year 2018